# Linked list add and remove function

Tags: java

I am trying to create a linked list with items, and it seems to be adding to the list because i added three and the length says it has 3 items in the list.

How ever my delete function is not working i am trying delete a specific item from the list from the list which has three items but it just returns false and doesn't remove the item from the list

```
public void tableInsert (T newItem) throws TableException {
    if (head == null) 
        head = new Node(newItem);
    else {
        Node tmp = head;
        while (tmp.getNext() != null)
            tmp = tmp.getNext();
        tmp.setNext(new Node(newItem));
    }
}
```

this is the delete function

```
public boolean tableDelete (KT searchKey) {
    if (head.getItem() == searchKey) {
        head = head.getNext();
        return true;
    }

    Node current = head.getNext();
    Node prev = head;

    while (current!= null) {
        if (current.getItem() == searchKey){
            prev.setNext(current.getNext());
            return true;
        }
        prev = current;
        current = current.getNext();
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Try debugging your code.

Comment: The first step would be to indent your code properly. There even seems to be a couple of braces missing here.

Comment: The `equals` thing suggested by @NPE seems like the best bet.  My second guess would be forgetting to set the item in the `Node` constructor.

Comment: `searchKey` isn't any primitive data, don't use `==` for comparing it

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the problem is the equality comparison using `==`. This compares object references, whereas you might need to perform a deep(er) comparison of `current.getItem()` against `searchKey`.

Answer (score 0):

By using "==" comparation you only compare references of the objects (so you always get false unless you compare references to the same objects). Your object should implement **comparable** (quite some material about it on the Internet) or include your own function which compares appropriate fields etc.

What is more, why do you insert object type T, but delete object type KT?

Comment: Essentially trying to duplicate or convert this Table array based to LinkedList based

http://www.cs.vassar.edu/~cs102/code/Packages/Tables/TableArrayBased.java